# Appharbor - Build failure - Either the Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header

Tags: appharbor

I have a working ASP. NET Web application on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). But since yesterday when we commit changes,  we are getting build error as follows.

Could it be related to the code we are  deploying?

```
Code-InvalidArgument-Code
Message-Either the Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified, not both-Message
ArgumentValue-
00ae7439f3e3d4956d325c6868fe1853b48671a4db49deb209c1ce0691b5dc66c9dcda413d6c1223df705c8b085e088eee552ed255fb60068878d386a150d21bad/008faea860883ff98643593aa166cdf07b19d415bc8abdc1132a2d1ed9f9d7fa4b5dbe316f6bd04eb77d714fd3bfb2e259ac4bdbbcc8e839d3569227c8e51ba83d-ArgumentValue
ArgumentName-Authorization-ArgumentName
RequestId-B2EC5601E4D4C6C8-RequestId
HostId-6ot5sQ9xgCaC6GgipaU5ULqd9TfvF23IH6bcLmc8Wmupe1UP5GeR8vGPws5b71iN-HostId
-Error
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Also consider opening a ticket on AppHarbor by emailing support@appharbor.com